# How to use logic to perform operations only on date objects in an array in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a script which will read a particular column in a spreadsheet, and only if the item in a particular cell is a date object (which Google scripts automatically renders from our format - MM/dd/yyyy) Google's date object gives all time parameters, as such:

```
Sat Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2014
```

I ONLY want the data stored from the column if it is a date object, so what logic would I put in an if() statement to accomplish this? I tried using regularexpressions, as follows

```
var dateFormat = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\sGMT-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{4}');

var line = "Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2015";
Logger.log(dateFormat.test(line));
```

This test returns TRUE. So why does the logic not work directly on date objects?
And if you know about date objects in Apps scripts, where can I find information on operating on date objects. I am interested in detecting a date is 45 days in the future, 30 days in the future, and 15 days, and sending corresponding alerts for these dates coming up, then after 15 days sending an alert every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test does not work on Date objects because they are Date objects and not String objects.

use the `instanceof` operator (`cellValue instanceof Date`) to find out if it's a date.

Comment: would you know about working with dates mathematically, that is, setting certain events at certain time periods based on a date? If there is a link on the web you can forward me that would be beneficial i cannot find good infomration

Comment: just search here stackowerflow with `[google-apps-script] date`. You'll find lots of info. JS Date objects are nasty beasts, I prefer convert them to UNIX timestamps for calculations.